# Hash airflow in the first line of dag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-2.x, google-cloud-composer-2

Is there any significance of adding '''# airflow''' as the first line in airflow dag.
Because python will treat it as a comment.

Comment: can you give more details ? do you this comment ? did you see it in some docs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; no, there is no significance. I would remove it to avoid any confusion.

I suspect you might have seen this somewhere on the internet, where the topic was around Airflow & DAG processing. Airflow uses a heuristic to discover files that potentially contain DAG objects: it checks if the words "airflow" and "DAG" exist in the file. I suspect adding `"# airflow"` might have been a workaround for Airflow to parse that script. However, in normal circumstances this should not be needed: if you have a `DAG` object in your script, you will need to import `from airflow import DAG`, which automatically makes Airflow parse that script, so an additional comment `"# airflow"` is therefore not needed.